# Changing Band Block size using GDAL

Tags: gdal

I have a strange Band block size in my geotiff file - `Block=566x1`.

How can I rearrange this size to `512x512`?

Here is complete gdalinfo:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Size is 566, 419
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (13.273016488845716,46.615000000000592)
Pixel Size = (0.030029097963144,-0.030000000000001)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  13.2730165,  46.6150000) ( 13d16'22.86"E, 46d36'54.00"N)
Lower Left  (  13.2730165,  34.0450000) ( 13d16'22.86"E, 34d 2'42.00"N)
Upper Right (  30.2694859,  46.6150000) ( 30d16'10.15"E, 46d36'54.00"N)
Lower Right (  30.2694859,  34.0450000) ( 30d16'10.15"E, 34d 2'42.00"N)
Center      (  21.7712512,  40.3300000) ( 21d46'16.50"E, 40d19'48.00"N)
Band 1 Block=566x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  Description = u10
Band 2 Block=566x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = v10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `TILED=YES` [creation option of the GTiff driver](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#creation-options), e.g:

`gdal_translate -co TILED=YES -co BLOCKXSIZE=512 -co BLOCKYSIZE=512 src.tif dst.tif`